# how to return a value from function?

Tags: javascript

I need to return a value from my function where I'm using 2 for loop and if statement

```
function getTextColor(context) {
  var selection = context.selection;
  for(var i = 0; i < selection.count(); i++){
    var layer = selection[i];
    const attr = layer.CSSAttributes()
    const regex = /#\w{6}/
    for (let i = 0; i < attr.length; i++){
      let color = attr[i].match(regex)
      if (color)
        return color[0]   // I need to return this value from my function


    }

  }

}
```

Comment: So what is not working with that code above? Only issue I see is you do no return anything if the loops do not find anything.

Comment: return color[0]; that  is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an auxiliary variable to that. So, after all the loops, you can send the value to return. But, keep in mind that your function can return a `null` value.

```
function getTextColor(context) {
  let aux = null;
  const selection = context.selection;
  for (let i = 0; i < selection.count(); i++) {
    const layer = selection[i];
    const attr = layer.CSSAttributes();
    const regex = /#\w{6}/;
    for (let i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
      let color = attr[i].match(regex);
      if (color)
        aux = color[0];
    }
  }
  return aux;
}
```

Comment: So you keep looping after you already find it??? seems like a waste of CPU

Answer (score -4):

You can simply call the function as you initialize the variable. in this case the variable color will hold the color which your function returns.

```js
var color = getTextColor(context);

function getTextColor(context) {
  var selection = context.selection;
  for(var i = 0; i < selection.count(); i++){
    var layer = selection[i];
    const attr = layer.CSSAttributes()
    const regex = /#\w{6}/
    for (let i = 0; i < attr.length; i++){
      let color = attr[i].match(regex)
      if (color)
        return color[0]   // I need to return this value from my function
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, `var color = getTextColor(context);` is how you call a function. All you've accomplished is `getTextColor` is no longer a callable function; instead, its name is `color`.  Try `var foo = function bar() { return 2; }` in your browser console, then try calling `bar()`.